# How can I add a property to my custom element and be able to fire an action on its value change

Tags: javascript, html, custom-element

In fact the title does not fully cover what I'm after. I have created my own select element. It's made of some div, ul/li and hidden input elements.It's of course got the markup and javascript part. Here's the html:

```
<div id="ddlCars" class="ma-select" style="width:350px;">
        <div class="ma-select-box"><input class="ma-select-box-filter" type="text"></div>
        <div class="ma-select-options">
            <ul class="ma-select-ul">
                <li class="ma-select-li ma-visible-option" optvalue="7">MERCEDES</li>
                <li class="ma-select-li ma-visible-option" optvalue="10">BMW</li>
                <li class="ma-select-li ma-visible-option" optvalue="14">AUDI</li>
                <li class="ma-select-li ma-visible-option" optvalue="3">VOLKSWAGEN</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <input class="ma-select-hidden"  type="hidden">
    </div>
```

The javascript code is just a bunch of functions that catch events like click, hover, keyup etc and are bound to the above elements (by class) on ready method. I haven't declared any type for this custom select.

With a normal DOM select element I am able to do this:

```
 document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex=0;
```

Now I would like to achieve the something similar. I can find the wrapper div by id or class name. But is there a way I can do something something like this?

```
$('#ddlCars').selectedIndex=1;
```

So somehow, I need to add a property to my custom select and catch its change to set the selelcted value to the corresponding li element.

Comment: Maybe the jquery .change() method will trigger an event when prop changes ?

Comment: You should use `Object.defineProperty()` and create a setter function both to set the property value and do whatever you like to do along with it. Similarly a getter function can help you to patch actions when it's value is read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get the same behaviour as the select element you might want to extend the element like you would to a normal class. perhaps use a library like Polymer, github.com/richardanaya/webblock or github.com/SaulDoesCode/Crafter.js to design your custom element this way.

Otherwise should you implement it manually use getters and setters.
You would have to use Object.defineProperty to create such custom behaviour using getters and setters on elements.

here is a  nifty little function to make that easier

```
   function newGetSet(element ,key, get, set) {
         Object.defineProperty(element, key, {
           set: set,
           get: get
         });
   }
   // then use it - just a rough example 
   newGetSet( myElement , 'selectedIndex' , index => {
      // perhaps then apply a class or something to make it active
      document.querySelectorAll('ul > li')[index].classList.add('active');
   }, () => {
      let active_index = 0;
      Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('ul > li')).forEach((item,index) => {
          if(item.classList.contains('active')) active_index = index;
      });
      return active_index;
   });
```

of course as mentioned by another answer , to get the desired effect on the items in the custom select list perhaps attach en EventListener.

so consider that the property "selectedIndex" has been defined on the parent element thus you could simply add Listeners which would update the parent.

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('ul > li')].forEach((item,index) => {
    item.addEventListener('click',evt => {
       item.parentNode.selectedIndex = index;
    });
});
```

Comment: This seems to be a perfect solution. Thanks for the code.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid `.selectedIndex` only works with the `<select>` element. If you really want to work with something similar, try

```
$('ul li').live('click', function() 
{
    var index =  $(this).index();
});
```

Use `.delegate` instead of `.live` if you are using jQuery 1.9+ as it has been deprecated.

Comment: [As of **jQuery 1.7**, `.delegate()` has been superseded by the `.on()` method.](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)